# Use function pointer in template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

This is a selection of my class

```
template <typename TValue, typename TPred = std::less<TValue> >
class BinarySearchTree {
public:
BinarySearchTree<TValue, TPred> &operator=(BinarySearchTree<TValue, TPred> const &tree) {
    if (this != &tree) {
        tree.VisitInOrder(Insert);
    }
    return *this;
}
bool Insert(TValue const &value) {
    return m_Insert(value, pRoot);
}
template <typename TVisitor> void VisitInOrder(TVisitor visitor) const;
...
};
```

and the following sequence wont work: `VisitInOrder(Insert)` because my compiler says that there are arguments missing

but my main looks like this and there i can use the function without its arguments:

```
void Print(int const x) { cout << x << endl; }

int main() {
    BinarySearchTree<int> obj1, obj2, obj3;
    obj1.Insert(10);
    obj1.VisitInOrder(Print);
    return 0;
}
```

full code here: http://pastebin.com/TJmAgwdu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `Insert` is a member function, which means it accepts an implicit `this` pointer. You have to use `std::bind()` if you want to get a unary functor out of `Insert()`:

```
if (this != &tree) {
    tree.VisitInOrder(
        std::bind(&BinarySearchTree::Insert, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=60bdbd4a47cf69cdc2e01a83bb5f8cae-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc) showing the program compiling when the following assignment is present:

```
obj3 = obj1;
```